# Clases o metodos en android

Tags: android

Tengo 2 Activity:

Activity 1

```
class Activity 1{

   public void Cargar(){
      int carga = 1;
   }

}
```

en el ejemplo se llama la función y crea una variable ahí todo bien

Activity 2

```
class Activity2 {

   Cargar();

}
```

el problema es como cargo una función o método desde otra clase?

Comment: Define el método a llamar como static, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define tu método que deseas llamar desde otra clase como `public` y `static` :

```
class Activity 1{

   public static void Cargar(){
      int carga = 1;
   }

}
```

de esta forma puedes llamar el método desde otra clase:

```
class Activity2 {

   //Llama método Cargar de clase Activity.
   Activity.Cargar();

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono